# jOOQ Return a POJO, and ID from from joined table

Tags: java, jooq

I've got a table WARNINGS_HISTORY which is a list of events, each event links to a WARNINGS row which contains details for the event. I've been able to retrieve a list of WARNINGS (`List<Warnings>`) which occurred in a specific time frame. But I also need to have the  WARNINGS_HISTORY.ID. So I need the below SQL to return something like `Map<Integer, Warnings>`, `List<List<Integer, Warnings>>` or `List<List<WarningsHistory, Warnings>>` where the Integer field is theWARNINGS_HISTORY.ID.

Any hints as to how to make this happen?

```
public List<Warnings> load(int maxId, LocalDateTime timestampStart,LocalDateTime timestampEnd) {
    return create.select(WARNINGS.fields())
            .from(WARNINGS_HISTORY)
            .innerJoin(WARNINGS).using(WARNINGS.SIDFILENAME)
            .where(WARNINGS_HISTORY.IID.greaterThan(maxId))
            .and(WARNINGS_HISTORY.DTCREATEDATE.greaterOrEqual(timestampStart))
            .and(WARNINGS_HISTORY.DTCREATEDATE.lessOrEqual(timestampEnd))
            .orderBy(WARNINGS_HISTORY.IID.asc())
            .fetch().into(Warnings.class);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write this:

```
public Map<Integer, Warnings> load(
        int maxId, 
        LocalDateTime timestampStart,
        LocalDateTime timestampEnd) {
    return create
            .select(WARNINGS.fields())
            .select(WARNINGS_HISTORY.ID) // Add the ID to the SELECT list
            .from(WARNINGS_HISTORY)
            .innerJoin(WARNINGS).using(WARNINGS.SIDFILENAME)
            .where(WARNINGS_HISTORY.IID.greaterThan(maxId))
            .and(WARNINGS_HISTORY.DTCREATEDATE.greaterOrEqual(timestampStart))
            .and(WARNINGS_HISTORY.DTCREATEDATE.lessOrEqual(timestampEnd))
            .orderBy(WARNINGS_HISTORY.IID.asc())
            .fetchMap(

                // Mapping the Map key is straight forward
                r -> r.get(WARNINGS_HISTORY.ID),

                // Mapping the Map value needs an extra step to avoid the ambiguity
                // between WARNINGS.ID and WARNINGS_HISTORY.ID when you use into(Class),
                // i.e. when you use jOOQ's DefaultRecordMapper
                r -> r.into(WARNINGS).into(Warnings.class)
            );
}
```

The above makes use of [`ResultQuery.fetchMap(RecordMapper, RecordMapper)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchMap-org.jooq.RecordMapper-org.jooq.RecordMapper-)